# Sony Playmemories SDK For Aplha & NEX

Tags: sdk, camera, sony

Do you plan to publish an SDK for the Aplha and NEX cameras?  You publish some apps yourself and it would be good to see what the developer community out there could do with these devices.

In particular I would like to see a Studio app that caused the OLED viewfinder to show a well exposed image regardless of manual camera settings.  That would allow me to use the A6000, A7R and the like in a studio with high power studio strobes.

Many thanks

Nick SS

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not Sony.

Comment: Sony says on it's webpage that they parses stackoveflow daily for questions about development for Sony devices

Answer (score 9):

The original poster is/was asking Sony how to write/develop *embedded* applications for Sony cameras that support after-the-fact install of "apps" from the Sony "PlayMemories" application ( aka "store").    There is also a kinda related ( but technically very different ) SDK by Sony that is called the "remote api", which is used for apps outside the camera ( android and ios phones typically) to assist them in remotely performing actions *to* the camera over WiFi.     One is an in-camera app, the other is an out-of-camera app.

The short answer is that there has been some reverse-engineering to discover that these camera/s aparently run some variant of android itself AND someone has figured out how to duplicate the process of installing your own "app" to the camera.  see here: https://github.com/ma1co/Sony-PMCA-RE

Answer (score 0):

Currently only Camera Remote API(beta) is published and constantly being updated with new capabilities and new devices.

Comment: I would like to write a play memories camera app for my A7. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to Sony's SDK site.  Its still in Beta and is only apk format.

https://developer.sony.com/downloads/camera-file/sony-camera-remote-api-beta-sdk/

I looked over the documentation from the Sony SDK site and added the rest of the functions for the A6000 camera.  You can find it on git hub.  Still a bit of a work in progress and I have not yet tested all the functions.  This repo will generate a jar file that you can use in any apk applications.

https://github.com/keyserSoze42/SonySDK

Here is the repo to the apk that Sony built.  I parsed out the sdk part and this uses the sdk built from the other repo.  You should be able to find it in the libs directory.

github.com/keyserSoze42/SonySampleApp

Comment: question is about playmemories apps which are more powerful, then published API, which only allow for remote control